# assigning char* to a void* field

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, void-pointers

I need to make a program that reads file lines and saves them in a linked queue. I am using a library that uses a void* data field in each node.

When I try to print all the lines stored, the program repeats the last line read, for the number of lines stored in the file.

I think, since I am passing a pointer to the data field, each time I read a new line the value stored changes. Is there a way to prevent it?

Attaching the function I'm working with and the queue functions and structure.

```
void* readfile(void* arg){
   FILE* fp;
   fp = fopen((char*)arg, "r");
   if(fp==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", (char*)arg);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   char* line= malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE); // #define BUFSIZE 1024

   while(fgets(line, BUFSIZE, fp)!=NULL){
      insert_tail(deque_12, (void*)line);
   }
   puts("File read");
   fclose(fp);
   return NULL; 
}
```

```
> deque.h 

typedef struct node{
   void* data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}Node_t;

typedef struct deque{
   Node_t *head;
   Node_t *tail;
}Deque_t;

void insert_tail(Deque_t* d, void* data){

   Node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node_t*));

   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = NULL;

   if(d->head == NULL){
      newNode->prev = NULL;
      d->head = newNode;
   }
   else{
      newNode->prev = d->tail;
      d->tail->next = newNode;
   }
   d->tail = newNode;
}
```

Comment: In C, all `void *` pointers are implicitly convertible to almost any other pointer type, and vice versa. The only pointer that's not possible to convert is pointers to functions. So you can assign a `void *` value to a `char *` variable without any issues.

Comment: You have only 1 `malloc` for the data buffer, and therefore all the elements in your queue point to the same buffer. You need to `malloc` a buffer per element. You also need to `free` every `malloc`ed buffer to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Re “ feel like, since I am passing a pointer to the data field, each time I read a new line the value changes”: “I feel like” is not a problem description. Is the value changing? What evidence do you have? What behavior of the program do you observe? Specifically, what output does it print or what values do you see in the debugger? What behavior do you think you should see instead? If you want debugging help, edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil The value is the same as the last line read for each node. Edited the question

Comment: @wohlstad how should I edit my code to do so? Tried adding `line= realloc(line,sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);` inside the while at the end but didn't work

Comment: @DravStart you should `malloc` a new `line` inside the loop after calling `insert_tail`. Also don't forget the eventual `free`s. BTW - `realloc` is wrong here because it will free the previous allocation.

Comment: @wohlstad alright it works! I'll be handling the `free`s in a different function. Thank you

Comment: about a zillion dupes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+fgets+last+line)

Comment: please provide something one could compile, complete. Helps others help you...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code in `readfile`:

```
    char* line= malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE); // #define BUFSIZE 1024

   while(fgets(line, BUFSIZE, fp)!=NULL){
      insert_tail(deque_12, (void*)line);
   }
```

That allocates one piece of memory for the buffer and assigns its address to `line`. Then, for every line of input, it calls `insert_tail` to crate a new node that points to `line`.

The result is that every node points to the same piece of memory, the one pointed to by `line`.

To fix this, you must allocate a different piece of memory for the data of every line. You can do this by allocating memory for each line in the loop in `readfile` or in the `insert_tail` routine and, after memory is successfully allocated, copying the data from `line` into the newly allocated memory. Then, of course, the `data` of the new node must be set to point to the newly allocated memory, not to `line`.

> assigning char* to a void* field

This problem has nothing to do with converting a `char *` value to a `void *` value.